# Variable scope in PHP

Tags: php, scope

I have an issue with php. The  following code generates the error "PHP Warning:  mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given[...]" on the line containing the mysqli_query

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
    $table = "prjsuggestions";
    /$mysqli = NULL;
    if(!empty($_POST['posttext'])){
        $pnameempty = empty($_POST['postname']);
        $ynameempty = empty($_POST['name']);
        if($pnameempty || $ynameempty){
        }
        else{
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "progclub", "", "progclub");
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }
            //successful query normally occurs here but code fails w/ or /wo it.
        }
    }
    else{
       printf("No information posted.");
    }
?>
<title>Bucknell Programming Club</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="posts">
<?php
    $offset = 0;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$table}";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    if($result !== FALSE){
        //while(($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) !== NULL){
            echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
            $post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $author = $post['name'];
            printf("Author: %s\n", $author);
            echo "<br />";
            printf("Post title: %s\n", $post['title']);
            echo "<br />";
            printf("%s\n", $post['text']);
            echo "<hr />";
        //}
    }
    else printf("oh nooo!");
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that all queries have been checked out and are working correctly in phpmy, and that the original code contains an earlier query that adds data to the 'base, which also definitely works.

I have tried various combinations of static and global, and I have taken a thoroughish look at PHP's page on variable scope, alas I do not entirely understand it in this context (esp. given my inability to make my code work). Can somebody enlighten me as to the differing scopes here? I didn't think there should be any!!

Comment: 4 spaces before a line = code formatting. Select and tap `ctr-k` to do this.

Comment: Your scope looks okay, but it's impossible to tell, since you provide invalid and incomplete PHP. Show some code that at least works enough to produce the error.

Comment: I use other variable and *they* all stay in scope just fine! If it helps the actual connect procedure is inside an if statement, but I feel like that's just a spectre of C thinking haunting my analysis of the actual issue.

Comment: The devil's in the details. Please show us the actual code that fails, don't summarize it with comments! \*tsk tsk*

Comment: This gets weirder and weirder. Some of the line numbers in php's error logs are off by one, but only some of them. O_o. I will see if I can trim this down to something postable tomorrow, but for now, sleep.

Comment: If $mysqli is NULL then that usually means the connection failed. Do you have the password and hostname correct?

Comment: @steven - And even more important, is there an `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { ... }` to check for any connection errors?

Comment: And anyway, you should connect to the database and execute the query at the top of the file, and loop over the results where you want to print them. And put the PHP above the `<html>` tag to really sparate HTML and PHP.

Comment: Ok, here is my code. Thoughts?

Comment: `else printf("oh nooo!");` is really nice :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooohh. D'oh. Yeah. Scope. Perhaps I should have though more about the fact that the variable is only initialized when data is written. Oops. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the **[documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)** (specifically Example 1). There are a few example similar to yours.

The following should work, and it is similar to your code:

**Note how the first argument of `mysqli_query()` is in fact your variable `$mysqli`**. You were probably trying to put something else there.

Also, be sure to **check your connection**, like in the code below:

```
<html>
<head>    
<?php
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Use $mysqli */
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, "/* ... MySQL goes here... */") === TRUE) {
    /* Success! */
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
</body>
</html>
```